# Using JavaScript to change CSS values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I haven't found a good example of this, I have this CSS snippet.

```
#divname .jqplot-point-label {
     color: #000000;
}
```

I know how to change CSS if it's just the ID, or just the class, but in this case I'm not sure what the JavaScript would look like.

I'm trying

```
$('#divname .jqplot-point-label').css({'color':'#000000'});
```

But that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML? The code you provided there should work.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code, are you sure jquery has been loaded?

Comment: Your code works, I tested it : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/a9EU2/

Comment: is your jQuery invoked in $(document).ready(function(){ //code});?

Comment: try running `alert($('#divname .jqplot-point-label').length)` in firebug or chrome console (whichever u r using). If the returned value is 0 then either path given is wrong or you are running this code before the element(s) getting added to the DOM

Comment: It returned a 0, so I moved it to the end of the chart function, now it returns a 3.  But I need to redraw the div somehow.

Comment: It works fine now, I moved it to the end of my plot function.  I had a page refresh function trying to redraw it and this was reverting it back to the original CSS color I think.  

This is the function that worked

    plotName = $.jqplot('divName', values, { plot data etc... });
    $('#divname .jqplot-point-label').css({'color':'#ffffff'});

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to wrap your code in ready handler (your code is fine but missing to use ready handler will cause your code not to work):

```
$(function(){
  $('#divname .jqplot-point-label').css({'color':'#000000'});
});
```

I assume you are including jQuery in your page with correct path.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting inside the $(function() {}  it skips it.

Comment: @Jason: You should create an example at jsfiddle or jsbin

Answer (score -1):

use $('#divname.jqplot-point-label') as the selector. (no space between the id and class name).

$(#divname .jqplot) is looking for an element with class .jqplot with an ancestor of #divname.

Comment: he didn't say that he wants to change the CSS of an element with id and class given in question so we need to assume that his selector is working for him as his CSS style selector

Comment: I'm trying that now, the color doesn't change.  This is set before jqplot is called.  Initially it's set in the style block to #ffffff, which works fine. I want to change it if certain criteria are met.  Yes, jQuery is referenced and works fine with other functions.  I'm not sure if it needs to be invoked or not, I use other functions before this one.  Also I'm using jQuery Mobile for some things.

Comment: @sv_in you are correct. He didn't say that he was trying to call an id an a class name. I described what each did in the answer. I *should* have added a comment instead of an answer. Point taken.